# Java EE transaction behavior when WS client times out

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, transactions, ejb

I have published synchronous SOAP web service bound to HTTP transport using Java EE and JAX-WS. Does the Java EE specification mandate the JTA transaction to rollback, if the web service consumer times out before the service method returns?

I forced a client timeout with additional 70 seconds sleep before returning from the service method, which resulted in `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out` exception on SoapUI. The web service transaction indeed rolled back after returning.

Is this behavior mandated by the Java EE specification, expecting client TCP acknowledgement to commit the transaction? If so, what is the exact protocol? Or is this more SoapUI specific situation, which doesn't apply to all clients?

For clarification, I'm trying to simulate a scenario, where the network delay or failure during service **response** leads to client timeout.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction has nothing to do with timeout. The mandate for the transaction to be commit is if the bean method returns normally. If it returns exceptionally, be it due to internal errors or timeout exceptions, the transaction will be rolled back.

You can avoid rollback by wrapping the exception in a business exception that is marked with `@ApplicationException(rollback = false)`

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html

Answer (score 0):

What you ask cannot really be done. Or you try an asynchronous call. Or you could make another service by which the client can ask if a transaction suceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Today encounter this problem, or similar.

So i found a ProcessingException caused by SocketTimeoutException.
A ProcessingException is a runtime exception therefore rollback the transaction (my case is with ejb).

If you don't throw a RuntimeException you are good to go, so catch the exception and threated as a normal exception, do not let the return of a call to an method (ejb or cdi) to throw a runtime exception.

Obs: I didn't read any spec, so use this knowledge by your own terms.